# How to append parameter to GET request

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, backend

I'm kinda new to backend so I'm not sure how to append my parameter to my `GET` request which is then sent to the my server. Let's say I have 4 projects, each with `{projectID: 1, projectID: 2...}` and when I click on the first project with `projectID: 1` I will send a `GET request` to **localhost:3000/api/launch/projects/1**. But I have no idea how to write the route in my backend to get the **1** as parameter.
Here's the code:

```js
route.get(
    "/projects/",    // how to receive the projectID as parameter
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // ... some code
    const data = await launchServiceInstance.getProjectsByID(projectsID);  // projectID has to be 1
    }
  );
```

Comment: That looks like TypeScript, not JavaScript. Is this NodeJS or browser code?

Comment: `route` is not a JS built-in, so what framework/library are you using?

Comment: It's not clear for me but I think you can try add the `id` into route and get using `req.params.id` like this: `route.get("/projects/:id", async(...) => { const id = req.params.id });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understood well, but I'll try to answer. First, you should add 'id' to the route. Second, you can access the id with 'req.params.id'. So the code would be:

```
route.get(
    "/projects/:id",    // how to receive the projectID as parameter
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // ... some code
    const data = await launchServiceInstance.getProjectsByID(req.params.id);  // projectID has to be 1
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is server code you can access parameters (for `GET` request):

```js
route.get(
    "/projects/:projectsID", // add here to parameter
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
       const { projectsID } = request.params; // access parameter
       const data = await launchServiceInstance.getProjectsByID(projectsID);
    }
);
```